# numeric range in tcsh

Tags: shell, unix, tcsh

Suppose I have a bunch of files, the names of which contain a number, like this: xxx_1.txt, xxx_2.txt, ... xxx_42.txt

In bash, it's easy to operate on subsets of these files, e.g. `ls xxx_{1..33}.txt xxx_{35..41}`.

What would be the tcsh analog of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in mechanism to specify range patterns (except single character ranges) in `tcsh`. But you could, for example, use the `seq` utility (if it is available) together with `sed`:

```
ls `(seq 1 33; seq 35 41)|sed 's/^/xxx_/;s/$/.txt/'`
```

Comment: `seq` (at least the GNU coreutils version) can do its own formatting: `seq -f xxx_%.0f.txt 1 20`.  `info seq` for more information.